# jQuery cross site scripting - What was this

Tags: jquery

Vulnerability description

This page is using an older version of jQuery that is vulnerable to a Cross Site Scripting vulnerability. Many sites are using to select elements using location.hash that allows someone to inject script into the page. This problem was fixed in jQuery 1.6.3. 
This vulnerability affects /js/jquery.js. 
Discovered by: Scripting (jQuery_Audit.script). 
Attack details

```
Pattern found: 
/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.3.2
 * http://jquery.com
```

What was this means?

My website is currently using jQuery JavaScript Library v1.3.2

Is this will get trouble?

Comment: 1.3.2! I think this is a new record!

Comment: @JoeFrambach yea, my website also having new record on alexa which rank 4-6 in my country. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should keep your jQuery up to date. However, there are some breaking changes between jQuery versions. 1.7.x started deprecating some event delegations. 2.x started removing support for older browsers.

For your case, I suggest updating your jQuery library to 1.6.3 as recommended. Then thoroughly test your site to make sure everything still works.

If 1.6.3 still works, then I suggest updating to 1.7.2. Then thoroughly test your site to make sure everything still works.

If 1.7.2 still works, then decide if you want to continue supporting older browsers like IE8. If yes, then try updating to 1.11.1. If no, then try updating to 2.1.1. These are the latest versions.

This may not be an easy thing to do. If you stop at 1.6.3, that is understandable and is fine.

Comment: Joe Frambach, Thanks for the beautiful explanation.

Comment: Check https://code.jquery.com/jquery/ for the latest version of 1.x (currently it is 1.12.4).

Answer (score 2):

Cross site scripting is not JQuery or JavaScript only vulnerability.
I highly recommend you read following two article about the subject

- [What is Cross Site Scripting and How Can You Fix it?](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/)
- [XSS Attack Examples (Cross-Site Scripting Attacks)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/xss-attack-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

You may have scanned your site using some tool. These tools work on productions. And as you know that all the jQuery versions before 1.6.3 are vulnerable to Cross Site Scripting using location.hash parameter, that's why it is giving you a security vulnerability.

It is recommended that you update your jQuery version to the latest. And keep in mind that the dependencies, jQuery version 2.x doesn't supports IE, and other older versions of browsers.